# Javascript to java and issue with form and hidden element

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am trying to use a handleFileSelect method to read some stuff from a file the user specifies and then use its content to do things with java.

The handleFileSelect method:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                var text = evt.target.result;
                var lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
                document.getElementById('lines').value = lines;
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file,"UTF-8");
    }
```

If I put an alert after the var lines it does show the content that in the file is one login name per line (it shows it as a comma delimited string in the alert).  This tells me that at least up to this point the reading of the file is good.

Also, if you turn on developer tools in Chrome, I can see the hidden element with id lines is set to the list of comma delimited logins.  Sweet.  Now, however, right after I tried to use jsp with the following, but it never does anything:

```
<%
    if (request.getParameter("lines") != null) {
        String line = request.getParameter("lines");
        System.out.println("line: " + line);
        %>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("line: here");
            </script>
        <%
    }
    %>
```

I guess it does not do anything because I have no form wrapping the inputs.  So, I put in a form line:

```
<form method="post" id="ADD" name="ADD" action="">
```

Now, it hits the request.getParameter if..then section, but the hidden element lines is empty.

I am confused on how to get done what I need to do.  Why is hidden element lines empty if I use a form?  Any other way to get the javascript var lines to my java side?

handleFileSelector is called by windows.onload = init;

```
function init() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            if (window.requestFileSystem) {
                initFS();
                document.querySelector('.readButton').addEventListener('click',
                        function(evt) {
                            alert("Here in readbutton with " + evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase());
                            if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
                                handleFileSelect(evt);
                            }
                        }, false);
            }
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }
}
```

If I have no form element, but change handleFileSelect(evt) to use window.location.replace, I can get the file lines, but this seems bad as the files can be large.  The replace change looks like:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                var text = evt.target.result;
                var lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
                //var form_lines = document.getElementById("lines");
                window.location.replace("adduserroles.jsp?lines="+lines.toString());
                //form_lines.value = lines.toString();
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file,"UTF-8");
    }
```

With this change, I modified the jsp section as follows:

```
<%
    if(request.getParameter("lines") != null && !request.getParameter("lines").equals("")) {
        String[] lines = request.getParameter("lines").split(",");
        for (String line : lines) {

            System.out.println("line: " + line);
        }
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("line: here");
        </script>
        <%
    }

%>
```

I also changed the button to :

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <span class="readButton">
                    <p>
                        <input class="blue" type="submit" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" value="&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;" />
                    </p>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This shows me each line of information as desired.  I could then go on to do what I was planning, but again it seems like a horrible way to do it with the potential huge chain of lines passed in via I guess a default GET after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Please share the code that how `lines` is defined in JSP? From where `handleFileSelect` function is called?

Comment: If I had to guess, you said the hidden `input` had an `id` of lines. The input also requires the `name` attribute to be included in the post parameters

Comment: Did you submit the form? Just having a form won't do anything if you don't submit it.

Comment: The handleFileSelect is called with:

Comment: The hidden input has name and id, so that is not it.  See I added more information you requested to the main question.

Comment: I added a form, but set it to method="GET." This shows what is at issue.  When I click on button that triggers the handleFileSelect, it shows that it has submitted with form elements.  I was expecting it to just set the lines hidden element, but it looks like it is submitting the form.  It does not set lines hidden element even though I put document.getElementById('lines').value = stuff in the handleFileSelect method.  I see on url one it finishes reading the file: http://127.0.0.1/myapp.jsp?projAcro=Toast?files=file.txt?lines= (see lines is null).

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

This was a silly problem that took a lot of time. If you use

```
<button>
```

It defaults to being a submit button, which was causing an issue because the handleFileSelect is async process that leaves that method before it completes its work if you are using a small file.  In my case, my file only had a 100 lines.  This means it was  completing its submit before the lines variable had the lines from the file.  The work around was to change

```
<button> to <button type="button">.
```

I also found in my wanderings a better handleFileSelect that reports errors better:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            var contents = evt.target.result,
                error    = evt.target.error;

            if (error !== null) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.ENCODING_ERR:
                        console.error("Encoding error!");
                        break;

                    case error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                        console.error("File not found!");
                        break;

                    case error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                        console.error("File could not be read!");
                        break;

                    case error.SECURITY_ERR:
                        console.error("Security issue with file!");
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.error("I have no idea what's wrong!");
                }
            } else {
                var mylines = contents.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
                document.getElementById('lines').value = mylines.toString();
                //window.location.replace("adduserroles.jsp?lines="+lines.toString());
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file,"UTF-8");
   }
```